# Pushing to Array in promising array is empty out side of the promise

Tags: arrays, node.js, promise, sequelize.js

```
     findCartItem:function(req,res){


    const myArray = [];

console.log('=====step:1=====');

db.Carts.findAll({
    where: {
        UserId: req.params.user
    }
}).then(data => {
    console.log('=====step:3=====');
for(let i =0;i<data.length;i++){
    db.Products.findOne({
        where: {
            id: data[0].dataValues.ProductInfo
        }
    }).then(cartData => {

        console.log('=====step:5=====');
        console.log(cartData.dataValues);
        const createdOn = getDbDate(cartData.dataValues.createdAt);
        let theProduct = {
            id: cartData.dataValues.id,
            userId: cartData.dataValues.userId,
            productName: cartData.dataValues.productName,
            serialNumber: cartData.dataValues.serialNumber,
            category: cartData.dataValues.category,
            price: cartData.dataValues.price,
            productDescription: cartData.dataValues.productDescription,
            condition: cartData.dataValues.condition,
            warranty: cartData.dataValues.warranty,
            packaging: cartData.dataValues.packaging,
            userUploadImage1: cartData.dataValues.userUploadImage1,
            userUploadImage2: cartData.dataValues.userUploadImage2,
            status: cartData.dataValues.status,
            verified: cartData.dataValues.verified,
            createdAt: createdOn
        };
        console.log('=====step:6=====');
        myArray.push(theProduct);
        /*now array is being populated*/
        console.log(myArray)
    });
}
    console.log('=====step:4=====');/*even at this point, array hasn't been populated*/
 res.send(myArray)
}).catch(err => console.log(err));

console.log('=====step:2=====');/*at this point array hasn't been populated yet*/
console.log(myArray);

    }
```

I cannot figure out why outside of the promise the array dumps its content. Any help with be greatly appreciated.
The code first defines the array at the top 
then it checks all the products the the user has in his cart with his user id 
then it takes all the products that he has (for this i took out the loop until i figure out why its not working) in the cart db. then it takes all that data and finds all the products details that each product has. then it adds the correct date format and pushes it to the array but out side of the promise it is gone.

Comment: Please format and indent your code properly so we can read it more easily.  You can use the "edit" link to fix it.

Comment: it will be a loop but i took out the loop because it wasn't working before the loop so there will be multiple items going in the array

Comment: i put the loop back in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess problem stems because of the lack of understanding that last `console.log(myArray)` (step 2) is not executed after `myArray.push()` (step 6), rather before any of the then() callback have triggered.

I have annotated your code with few step logs which might help to understand it better:

```
function findCartItem (req, res) {

    const myArray = [];

    console.log('=====step:1=====');

    db.Carts.findAll({
        where: {
            UserId: req.params.user
        }
    }).then(data => {
        console.log('=====step:3=====');
        db.Products.findOne({
            where: {
                id: data[0].dataValues.ProductInfo
            }
        }).then(cartData => {

            console.log('=====step:5=====');
            console.log(cartData.dataValues);
            const createdOn = getDbDate(cartData.dataValues.createdAt);
            let theProduct = {
                id: cartData.dataValues.id,
                userId: cartData.dataValues.userId,
                productName: cartData.dataValues.productName,
                serialNumber: cartData.dataValues.serialNumber,
                category: cartData.dataValues.category,
                price: cartData.dataValues.price,
                productDescription: cartData.dataValues.productDescription,
                condition: cartData.dataValues.condition,
                warranty: cartData.dataValues.warranty,
                packaging: cartData.dataValues.packaging,
                userUploadImage1: cartData.dataValues.userUploadImage1,
                userUploadImage2: cartData.dataValues.userUploadImage2,
                status: cartData.dataValues.status,
                verified: cartData.dataValues.verified,
                createdAt: createdOn
            };
            console.log('=====step:6=====');
            myArray.push(theProduct);
            res.send(myArray);
            /*now array is being populated*/
            console.log(myArray)
        });

        console.log('=====step:4=====');
        /*even at this point, array hasn't been populated*/
        console.log(myArray)
        console.log(data[1].dataValues)

    }).catch(err => console.log(err));

    console.log('=====step:2=====');
    /*at this point array hasn't been populated yet*/
    console.log(myArray);
}
```

Following is async/await version, which is a bit simpler to understand.

```
async function findCartItem(req,res) {
    const myArray = [];

    let data = await db.Carts.findAll({
        where: {
            UserId: req.params.user
        }
    });

    let cartData = await db.Products.findOne({
        where: {
            id: data[0].dataValues.ProductInfo
        }
    });

    const createdOn = getDbDate(cartData.dataValues.createdAt);
    let theProduct = {
        id: cartData.dataValues.id,
        userId: cartData.dataValues.userId,
        productName: cartData.dataValues.productName,
        serialNumber: cartData.dataValues.serialNumber,
        category: cartData.dataValues.category,
        price: cartData.dataValues.price,
        productDescription: cartData.dataValues.productDescription,
        condition: cartData.dataValues.condition,
        warranty: cartData.dataValues.warranty,
        packaging: cartData.dataValues.packaging,
        userUploadImage1: cartData.dataValues.userUploadImage1,
        userUploadImage2: cartData.dataValues.userUploadImage2,
        status: cartData.dataValues.status,
        verified: cartData.dataValues.verified,
        createdAt: createdOn
    };
    console.log(myArray);
    console.log(data[1].dataValues);
    res.send(myArray);

}
```

Comment: how would i get the array to populate so i can send it to the front end

Comment: `res.send(myArray)` after step 6

Comment: I put all my code back in but the array is empty in res.send

Comment: I have edited my code. Try it, I guess it should work. Also, if you can transpile es7, you can use async/await version, which is simpler to understand

Comment: What's missing from this code is sending a response when there's an error.  The `await` version needs a `try/catch` around it and the non-await version needs to just send a response in the `.catch()`.

Answer (score 0):

Promises aren't correctly chained and nested without a good reason (so-called callback hell; something that promises are supposed to help with). This results in race condition and improper error handling.

`push` for results array is likely unneeded here; if there are multiple promises to resolve, they likely should be handled with `Promise.all` to run in parallel and retrieve results at once.

Instead of:

```
  db.Carts.findAll(...).then(data=>{
    for(let i =0;i<data.length;i++){
      db.Products.findOne(...).then(cartData=>{
        ...
        myArray.push(theProduct);
      });
    }
    console.log(myArray);
  }).catch(err =>console.log(err));
```

It should be:

```
  db.Carts.findAll(...).then(data=>{
    const cartPromises = [];
    for(let i =0;i<data.length;i++){
      const cartPromise = db.Products.findOne(...);
      cartPromises.push(cartPromise);
    }
    return Promise.all(cartPromises);
  }).then(cartResults=>{
     // process cart results array and get products array
     res.send(products);
  }).catch(err =>console.log(err));
```

Each promise that exists should be chained somewhere, and the chain should end with `catch`.

Comment: even when trying that the array is still empty and i put the loop i had back in and put a full version of the code up with a res.send in

Comment: @DavidHorn I updated the code with a loop, according to edits in the question.